# Post/Get handler in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I am doing a web application,
which creates a lot of post & get requests.

I can see all the requests using Develop Tools in Mozilla/Chrome, and also in Charles (application).

Is it possible to create a jquery/javascript function which will listen for all requests on current page, and will alert each request to me?

Something similiar to Jquery .click() function.

example:

```
$('body').post(function() {
alert(this.Url + this.Parameters);
});
```

I googled, and couldn't find, hope  there is a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,in Jquery you have **Global Ajax Event Handlers**

> These methods register handlers to be called when certain events, such
>   as initialization or completion, take place for any Ajax request on
>   the page

refer the [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Comment: if the request is not made by jquery, and is a javascript request, will it be called, or no?

Comment: @RuslanDascal: No, it won't.